# No response back from REST WS called by jQuery/JSON

Tags: java, jquery, json, web-services, rest

I know there is a lot of these posts but I couldn't really get this to work since I am new to both REST and JQuery:

I am using REST-WS with Java 5 and I am able to call it and get result back with "Poster" ,the firefox plugin to test it. When I call the URL below I should get the employee in order '0' in the map by calling the method "getCustomer" in the resource class shown below.

Although I am not able to get the result and getting an error "unknown "using jQuery and returning JSON when I call the REST from an html page with body as below:

```
<body>
        jQuery to REST <br><br>

       <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){

            $("button").click(function (){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://localhost:8081/RestDemo/services/customers/0",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.name);
                    },
                    error: function(e){  
                        alert("Error: " + e);  
                    } 
                });
             });

         });
       </script>
       <br>
       <br>
       <button>Return Customer</button>

      </body>
```

This is my Resource class:

```
package com.myeclipseide.ws;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import com.sun.jersey.spi.resource.Singleton;

@Produces("application/xml")
@Path("customers")
@Singleton
@XmlRootElement(name = "customers")
public class CustomerResource {

    private TreeMap<Integer, Customer> customerMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Customer>();

    public  CustomerResource() {
        // hardcode a single customer into the database for demonstration
        // purposes
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setName("Harold Abernathy");
        customer.setAddress("Sheffield, UK");
        addCustomer(customer);
    }

    @GET
    @XmlElement(name = "customer")
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        customers.addAll(customerMap.values());
        return customers;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getCustomer(@PathParam("id") int cId) {
        return  "{\"name\": \"unknown\", \"address\": -1}"; //customerMap.get(cId); 

    }

    @POST
    @Path("add")
    @Produces("text/html")
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public String addCustomer(Customer customer) {
         int id = customerMap.size();
         customer.setId(id);
         customerMap.put(id, customer);
         return "Customer " + customer.getName() + " added with Id " + id;
    }

}
```

I appreciate anyone's help,

Thanks!

Comment: Is your HTML page served from `http://localhost:8081/` as well?

Comment: Yes it is. actually it's the same app deployed on tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!

Returning `{"name": "unknown", "address": -1}` is right because that's exactly what is hard coded in my method return,

so i replaced `return  "{\"name\": \"unknown\", \"address\": -1}";` 
simply with a correct form which is

```
return  "{\"name\": \" " + customer.getName() + " \", \"address\": \"" + customer.getAddress() + "\"}";
```

and obviously it works!

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Now I just need to put an address in your database with a `"` character in it… (Get a library that does the quoting for you, please. Like that you never forget when it matters!)

Answer (score 0):

> I appreciate anyone's help,

If you are stumped, take a look at what is in the web countainer's log files.  If necessary, turn on debug logging.

The next thing would be to use your web browser's built-in "web developer" support to see what request is actually being sent.

Comment: This is what I get when I sniff the request/response with web developer:

Response Headers
Δ49858ms
  
  Content-Type:application/jsonDate:Tue, 31 Jul 2012 08:12:53 GMTServer:Apache-Coyote/1.1Transfer-Encoding:chunked
    
Response Body
Δ0ms
    
  {"name": "unknown", "address": -1}

Comment: apparently it does return something but is probably wrong because of the format i applied inmy return method.

sp I am sire it is returning "unknown" which is the name defined in the return of the method getCustomer.